# Estimate RH9 and RH15 from ERA5 on Earth Engine and time series of them

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to export RH on 9 and 15 o'clock to a CSV, but my code give me blank on column RH9 and RH15

```
var shapefile = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-dimasfqr/assets/karawang_kec_shp"),
geometry = 
/* color: #98ff00 */
/* shown: false */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[107.04729994333013, -5.903692785106611],
      [107.04729994333013, -7.120740977827176],
      [108.43707045114263, -7.120740977827176],
      [108.43707045114263, -5.903692785106611]]], null, false);
var listkec =['Majalaya','Tempuran','Ciampel','Cikampek','Tirta Jaya','Tegalwaru','Rawamerta','Rengas Dengklok','Kotabaru','Telukjambe Barat','Talagasari','Pangkalan','Telukjambe Timur','Banyu Sari','Pedes','Cilebar','Tirtamulya','Klari','Jayakerta','Karawang Timur','Cilamaya Kulon','Cilamaya Wetan','Kutawaluya','Pakisjaya','Batu Jaya','Lemahabang','Cibuaya','Karawang Barat','Jatisari','Purwasari']
print(listkec)
var ic9 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY").filterDate('2018-1-1','2023-1-31')
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2, 2, 'hour'))
var ic15 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY").filterDate('2018-1-1','2023-1-31')
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(8, 8, 'hour'))          
var dates = ee.List.sequence(0, 1825).map(function(day){
    return ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,01,01,'Asia/Jakarta').advance(day, "day");
  });
print(dates)
var kecamatan = shapefile.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WADMKC','Majalaya'));
var res = dates.map(function(date){
        var image = ic9.filterBounds(kecamatan).filterDate(date, ee.Date(date).advance(1, "day"))
        var image1 = image.select('temperature_2m');
        var b = ee.Image(273.15);
        var t9 = image1.min();
        var t91 = t9.clip(kecamatan);
        var temp9 = t91.subtract(b).reduceRegion({
             reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
             geometry: kecamatan.geometry(),
             scale: 10
            }).get("temperature_2m");
        var image2 = image.select('dewpoint_temperature_2m');
        var td9 = image2.min();
        var td91 = td9.clip(kecamatan);
        var tempd9 = td91.subtract(b).reduceRegion({
             reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
             geometry: kecamatan.geometry(),
             scale: 10
            }).get("dewpoint_temperature_2m");
        var image0 = ic15.filterBounds(kecamatan).filterDate(date, ee.Date(date).advance(1, "day"))
        var image01 = image0.select('temperature_2m');
        var b = ee.Image(273.15);
        var t15 = image01.min();
        var t151 = t15.clip(kecamatan);
        var temp15 = t151.subtract(b).reduceRegion({
             reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
             geometry: kecamatan.geometry(),
             scale: 10
            }).get("temperature_2m");
        var image02 = image0.select('dewpoint_temperature_2m');
        var td15 = image02.min();
        var td151 = td15.clip(kecamatan);
        var tempd15 = td151.subtract(b).reduceRegion({
             reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
             geometry: kecamatan.geometry(),
             scale: 10
            }).get("dewpoint_temperature_2m");
        // Calculate the vapor pressure (E) https://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/dochelp/QA/Basic/dewpoint.html
        var E0 = 0.611; // kPa
        var L_Rv = 5423; // K
        var T0 = 273; // K
        var K = 273.15
        var E9 = E0 * ee.Number(Math.E).pow((L_Rv) * ((1/T0) - (1/(tempd9+K)))); 
        var Es9 = E0 * ee.Number(Math.E).pow((L_Rv) * ((1/T0) - (1/(temp9+K))));
        var E15 = E0 * ee.Number(Math.E).pow((L_Rv) * ((1/T0) - (1/(tempd15+K))));
        var Es15 = E0 * ee.Number(Math.E).pow((L_Rv) * ((1/T0) - (1/(temp15+K))));
        var RH9 = 100* (E9/Es9);
        var RH15 = 100* (E15/Es15);
        return ee.Feature(null, {
          'date': ee.Date(date).advance(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-dd'),
          'Temp9': temp9,
          'TempD9': tempd9,
          'Temp15': temp15,
          'TempD15': tempd15,
          'E9': E9,
          'Es9':Es9,
          'RH9': RH9,
          'RH15': RH15,
          })});
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: ee.FeatureCollection(res),
description: 'jam9_Majalaya',
fileNamePrefix : "Percobaan_jam9_majalaya",
fileFormat: 'CSV',
selectors: ['date','Temp9','TempD9','Temp15','TempD15','E9','Es9','RH9','RH15']});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating `E9`, `Es9`, `E15`, `Es15`, `RH9`, `RH15`, you are using client-side operations (`/`, `*`, `-`) on server-side objects. Read up on that [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

I had problem running your script without exporting. The script ran out of memory when printing out the first features. There are a number of [best practices](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices) that are often good to adopt.

A couple of specific performance points for you script:

- Avoid clipping when you can
- Don't work with large lists, use collections when you can
- Reduce the number of times you invoke `reduceRegion()`. Combine reducers and/or apply it on multiple bands at the same time
- Don't use a scale smaller than your native imagery in `reduceRegion()`

You could perhaps implement it something like the below. Note that I don't know the formulas in your script, so some error might have sneaked in.

```
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-dimasfqr/assets/karawang_kec_shp")
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WADMKC', 'Majalaya'))
  .first()
  .geometry()
var startDate = '2018-01-01'
var endDate = '2023-02-01'
  
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
  .select(['dewpoint_temperature_2m', 'temperature_2m'])
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)  
  .filterBounds(aoi)
var rhCollection = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst('hour_8')
  .apply({
    primary: collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hour', 2)), 
    secondary: collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hour', 8)), 
    condition: ee.Filter.maxDifference({
      difference: 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
      leftField: 'system:time_start', 
      rightField: 'system:time_start'
    })
  }))
  .map(function (hour2) {
    var hour8 = ee.Image(hour2.get('hour_8'))
    var reduced = hour2.rename(['tempd9', 'temp9'])
      .addBands(hour8.rename(['tempd15', 'temp15']))
      .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
        geometry: aoi, 
        scale: 11132,
        maxPixels: 1e13
      })
    var temp9 = reduced.getNumber('temp9')
    var tempd9 = reduced.getNumber('tempd9')
    var temp15 = reduced.getNumber('temp15')
    var tempd15 = reduced.getNumber('tempd15')
    var E9 = calculateE(tempd9)
    var Es9 = calculateE(temp9)
    var E15 = calculateE(tempd15)
    var Es15 = calculateE(temp15)
    var RH9 = E9.divide(Es9).multiply(100)
    var RH15 = E15.divide(Es15).multiply(100)
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      date: hour2.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd'),
      Temp9: temp9,
      TempD9: tempd9,
      Temp15: temp15,
      TempD15: tempd15,
      E9: E9,
      Es9: Es9,
      RH9: RH9,
      RH15: RH15,
    })
  })
  

function calculateE(temp) {
  return ee.Number.expression(
    'E0 * exp((L_Rv) * ((1 / T0) - (1 / (temp + K))))', {
      E0: 0.611, // kPa
      L_Rv: 5423, // K
      T0: 273, // K
      K: 273.15,
      temp: temp
    }
  )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/14636f4550975d145de52bb43198512b

Comment: thank you, it works, i just correct the formula because the temp doesnt need to be added by K anymore, because it is in K already, thank you